# Select and then insert for each result

Tags: mysql, select, distinct, sql-insert

I have this table:

```
Table name: `user_offer_rels`
+----+--------+--------+-------+
| ID | userID | permID | state |
+----+--------+--------+-------+
| 1  | 1      | 1      | 0     |
| 2  | 1      | 2      | 0     |
| 3  | 2      | 1      | 0     |
| 4  | 2      | 2      | 0     |
+----+--------+--------+-------+
```

And I want to insert a new record for each result from this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userID FROM `user_offer_rels`

The results:
+--------+
| userID |
+--------+
| 1      |
| 2      |
+--------+
```

So for each one of that userID's I need to make something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `user_offer_rels` (userID, permID, state) VALUES (`the userID record from above`, 4, 0)
```

I have too much records so I cant make that insert one by one.

**EDIT:**

Desired Results of what that `user_offer_rels` table would look like after this INSERT runs:

```
+----+--------+--------+-------+
| ID | userID | permID | state |
+----+--------+--------+-------+
| 1  | 1      | 1      | 0     |
| 2  | 1      | 2      | 0     |
| 3  | 2      | 1      | 0     |
| 4  | 2      | 2      | 0     |
| 5  | 1      | 4      | 0     |
| 6  | 2      | 4      | 0     |
+----+--------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: @JNevill Ive added the desired results you've suggested

Comment: @forpas my mistake, I saw nbk's answer first because it appeared on top of yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `INSERT ... VALUES ...` use `INSERT ... SELECT ...`

```
INSERT INTO user_offer_rels (userID, permID, state) 
SELECT DISTINCT userID, 4, 0
FROM user_offer_rels
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2dfaa8e6e6fa3eafece2d93defe0aedf).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2):

You can use a select as insert statement

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user_offer_rels
>     (`ID` int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , `userID` int, `permID` int, `state` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO user_offer_rels
>     (`ID`, `userID`, `permID`, `state`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 1, 1, 0),
>     (2, 1, 2, 0),
>     (3, 2, 1, 0),
>     (4, 2, 2, 0)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO user_offer_rels (`userID`, `permID`, `state`)  SELECT DISTINCT userID,4, 0 FROM user_offer_rels
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM user_offer_rels
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | userID | permID | state
> -: | -----: | -----: | ----:
>  1 |      1 |      1 |     0
>  2 |      1 |      2 |     0
>  3 |      2 |      1 |     0
>  4 |      2 |      2 |     0
>  5 |      1 |      4 |     0
>  6 |      2 |      4 |     0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8978f831167a7744f63123bd1475b813)*

Comment: I've tryed this exactly and it just added one record for the userID 2

Comment: have you copied the code, as you see in the fiddle it works, maybe update your database

Comment: @RobertoSepúlveda That's not possible. Do you get two records back with this query: `SELECT DISTINCT userID,4, 0 FROM user_offer_rels` (both `1` and `2`)?

Comment: You're right, I've copied your code now and it works!